# Copy rotation / IK bug while rigging

Tags: rigging

at first, I would like to say that I'm totally newbie at Blender. I have a few experiences with similar program but I'm still beginner.

I try to learn rigging from this source: https://vimeo.com/30078317
Everything goes well (to 14:30 min of video) until setting rotation to control multiple bones.

I attached picture of my problem.
[image]

At 14:28 - everything goes well as in tutorial until this time.
At 14:47 - the foot flipped in tutorial but in my blender the "shin.L" bone is flipped well, the "foot.L" and "foot_IK.L" are flipped wrong.
At 15:22 - after setting rotation and axes the foot returns to correct position in tutorial and same in my blender but moving with controlling bone and moving affected bones are different and inverted (15:24)

I'm trying to solve it for two days but with my basic knowledge I can't find solution.

Thank you for help.

---

EDIT: According to suggestions in comments I uploaded my foots_test_002.blend file.

The creation of foot controls are in state of time 14:28.
According to tutorial you need to set "Copy rotation" to "roll_back.L" with properties: target "metarig", bone "roll_main.L", "X" checked, "Invert" checked, Space "Local Space" and "Local Space", influence "1.00", others checkboxes unchecked. I left it undone because you will probably want to see what it do in each step of setting up.

[image]

Regards
Shalladan

Comment: it may be easier if you upload the file , there are a lot of info needed for this

Comment: Instead of asking directions for some tutorial what is your goal? Do you want to make reverse foot IK rig? I can help with that.. I don't want to go through some tutorial..You should also name the question like How to setup reverse IK leg rig - so its easier to search for .)

Comment: thank you guys for useful comments, I attached file you needs for better understand with what issue i'm fighting